# Inheriting traits that keep types

Tags: scala

I am quite new to Scala and still a bit confused with its complicated type system.

I try to solve the following problem. I want to design classes that are members of mutable doubly linked lists (and more complicated data structures such as heaps). My objective is, of course, to be able to remove the objects from the data structures in constant time.

I designed the following trait :

```
trait DLLMember {
  var next: DLLMember = this
  var prev: DLLMember = this

  ...
}
```

with a few additional methods for adding and removing the object from the list.

The problem is, that when I am in my actual class, say :

```
class IntInDL(val v: Int) extends DLLMember
```

When parsing my list, IntInDL.next would return me a DLLMember type instead of IntInDL, which I have to cast to retrieve the value: this is not nice…

Is there a way to exploit Scala's type system to keep my work typesafe?

Answer (score 6):

It's a little roundabout, but the following should work:

```
trait DLLMember[T >: Null <: DLLMember[T]] { self : T =>
  var next: T = this
  var prev: T = this
  ...
}

class IntInDL(val v: Int) extends DLLMember[IntInDL]

var i = new IntInDL(3)
println(i.next.v) //prints 3
i.next = null //is valid
i.next = new IntInDL(1) //is valid
```

Essentially, what's going on here is that you are saying with `self : T =>` that the type parameter `T` must be a superclass of the class this trait is applied to. When you use the trait in `IntInDL` it is now known that the `next` and `prev` variables must be of some subtype of `IntInDL` because you supplied that as the type parameter. As such, you can use their members directly, without having to cast.

If you had supplied some other, arbitrary type that was not part of the hierarchy, `class IntInDL(val v: Int) extends DLLMember[String]` for example, it would simply have failed to compile.

Comment: It works nicely, however how would you allow null values to next and prev? (Other than by wrapping it in Options ?)

Comment: @scand1sk You'd have to add an additional bound on the type paramater, I've edited the answer to include it. Options are a good alternative though, even so.